# Incorrect progressbar value reported by the backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net

I build an app, which searches for different files through the computer, including Windows, ProgramFiles, etc folders.

- I've already done with the 'recursive' file search and it works now, this means all files/folders which are inaccessible will be skipped and the software will move on with the other available folders/files. But now, I have other issues...

The problem is that, for some odd reason, the application does not correctly report the progressbar value accordingly to the progress made in searching the files. This means that, the file search continues, **BUT** the progressbar is already 100%. The progressbar value **SHOULD** be 100% when the file search has been successfully completed.

```
====other code is already here ====

  Dim int As Integer = 0
Dim filecount As Integer = 0

Private Function GetFilesRecursive(ByVal path As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim lstResult As New List(Of String)
    Dim stkStack As New Stack(Of String)
    stkStack.Push(path)
    Do While (stkStack.Count > 0)
        Dim strDirectory As String = stkStack.Pop
        Try
            lstResult.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory, "*.*"))
            Dim strDirectoryName As String
            For Each strDirectoryName In Directory.GetDirectories(strDirectory)
                stkStack.Push(strDirectoryName)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Loop
    Return lstResult
End Function
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Quickscan.DoWork
   
     Try
       
        Dim i As Integer 
        Dim files As List(Of String) = GetFilesRecursive(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        For Each file As String In files
            
            Try
                Dim scanbox As New TextBox
                Dim read As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "db1.db")
                scanbox.Text = read.ToString
                Dim md5 As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
                Dim f As FileStream = New FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)
                f = New FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)
                md5.ComputeHash(f)
                Dim hash As Byte() = md5.Hash
                Dim buff As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
                Dim hashByte As Byte
                For Each hashByte In hash
                    buff.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", hashByte))
                Next

                If scanbox.Text.Contains(buff.ToString) Then
                    AddListItem(Listbox2, "" & file)
                    AddListItem2(Listbox2, "" & file & "")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
           
            If (Backgroundworker1.CancellationPending = True) Then

                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If
            SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.Labelscannedfiles, file & "")
            i = i + 1 
            SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.Label2, i)
            Dim pct As Integer = CInt(CDbl(i) / CDbl(files.Count) * 100)
            Backgroundworker1.ReportProgress(pct)
        Next file
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
    End Try

  Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles Backgroundworker1.ProgressChanged
   
    Label28.Text = "Computer scan is in progress... Please wait"
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage / 100
```

Any solution or help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Looking at you're code, I think your problem is you don't have a known completion point, so it's not really to calculate a percentage of an unknown.   It's just going to be purely based on the number of loop iterations.  You did have a file count variable at one stage, that is one option.  The other option might to be simply show an animation rather than a progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DoWork() method...

Change:

```
For Each file As String In GetFilesRecursive(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
```

To:

```
Dim i As Integer ' <- you didn't actually declare a counter before
Dim files As List(Of String) = GetFilesRecursive(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
For Each file As String In files
```

Now you can get the count from "files" and use that in your percentage calculation:

```
i = i + 1 ' <-- increment our "i" counter
SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.Label2, i)
Dim pct As Integer = CInt(CDbl(i) / CDbl(files.Count) * 100)
backgroundworker1.ReportProgress(pct)
```

Comment: Ok, this was the most helpful comment. Now, the problem is that, the file search is complete but the progressbar is only at 33%  instead of 100%.

Comment: Post your updated code by editing your original post, and I'll take another look.

Comment: Updated code looks good to me.  Double check to make sure that the Minimum/Maximum properties on your ProgressBar are at 0 and 100?

Comment: ...and you don't have any other code that is manipulating the ProgressBar?  Like maybe a Timer control?

Comment: Your solution definitely resolved the problem! The ProgressBar's maximum value was set to "300" on the Properties window. Don't know why, though, very weird, I didn't remember setting it that way. Either way, this problem has been resolved! Thank you very much for your help!